# Excel formulae: need way to determine if 3rd text character from right is "-"

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula

I have a column of hospital names. In most of them, the last three characters are "-" and the two-letter abbreviation for the state, e.g. "-CA". but some (out of hundreds) have the state name somewhere in the hospital name, e.g. "Texas Tech U Affil-Lubbock" or "Community Health of South Florida".

I'm trying to find a way to make Excel give the last two characters only if the 3rd character from the right is a dash ("-"), but trying to specify that character position seems impossible.

I tried:

=IF(RIGHT(H4,-3)="-",RIGHT(H4,2),"noabbrev") and get #VALUE

=IF(RIGHT(H4,3)="-??",(RIGHT(H4,2)),"noabbrev") and always get noabbrev for 
      all cells

At this point, I fear I need to use =RIGHT(H4,2) in order to get the bulk of the cells correctly and eyeball/correct the errors by hand.

Am I missing the obvious again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this formula if H4 is text:

```
=IF(MID(H4,LEN(H4)-2,1)="-",RIGHT(H4,2),"noabbrev")
```

Comment: Simple, elegant and ( [DOH!] ). Once again, I should have known that!

Answer (score 0):

If **A1** contains some text, then:

```
=Left(Right(A1,3),1)
```

should isolate the character you want.

Comment: This isolates the character and will likely be helpful in another case.  Thank you.